# Shell scripting error on HP-UNIX

Tags: shell, unix

While executing the below script, I'm getting an error:

```
Syntax error at line 1 : `(' is not expected.
```

```
sudo su - user1 -c "cd $HOME ; tar -cvf $HOME/mine.tar `cat /tmp/$LOGNAME/List`  "
```

where List file contains the name of some other files.

Please help me out with some solution.

Comment: `echo` the command (i.e. `echo "cd $HOME ; ..."`) and see what it shows

Comment: I particular, what is the contents of `/tmp/$LOGNAME/List`? Also, is there some context to the snippet in question? What is the script doing around that point?

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess that either $LOGNAME contains a ( or the contents of that List file do.

Comment: question also on [superuser](http://superuser.com/q/612003/4714)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your List file might contain a file name with a special character that isn't being escaped correctly when you do the `cat` command. Try passing the List file to tar with the `-T` argument instead so the file names don't have to be expanded on the command line:

```
tar -cvf $HOME/mine.tar -T /tmp/$LOGNAME/List
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `cat` to produce a list of files. `tar` usually supports the `--from-file` (`-T`) option to directly process files from a list:

```
sudo su - user1 -c "cd $HOME ; tar -cvf $HOME/mine.tar --files-from /tmp/$LOGNAME/List"
```

If your version of tar doesn't, consider using xargs instead:

```
sudo su - user1 -c "cd $HOME ; xargs tar -cvf $HOME/mine.tar < /tmp/$LOGNAME/List"
```

Comment: The `xargs` version will fail if `List` contains too many file names... Granted, that limit is fairly high, but it's still a possibility...